# Is Dextrose powder good for a one month old puppy?

Tags: veterinarian

Can I use dextrose powder for my one month old puppy? She is not feeling well and doesn't drink milk even if come from her mother.

Comment: In addition to - if your puppy is sick, you really ought to consult with a vet. And 'sick' could mean a whole load of different things - this disinterest in food is not a good sign but as is, its hard to tell if this is supplimenting other food or just trying to keep something in the puppy.

Comment: Dextrose is sugar. No other nutrients. Do you think feeding a human infant sugar would be a good idea? ... If you don't know what's wrong, a vet is almost always a better answer than the internet.